# Hyphenated abbreviation of component-sharing compound

Tags: hyphenation, compounds

In German it is unconspicuous to write 'An- oder Abwesenheit', but
writing 'pre- or absence' in English would be conspicuous and perhaps
either jocular or affectatious.  I cannot think of an example of this
kind of hyphenated abbreviation of one of two compounds sharing a
component that would seem natural in English.  Can you?  Or can you find
a literary example?

Comment: Over and underachiever, but often without hyphen,

Comment: @RustyCore, excellent.  I would consider this without a hyphen an error.

Comment: Can you do that in German with verbs of Latin origin? *ad- oder resorbieren?* or *re- oder demonstrieren*?

Answer (score 1):

One problem with "pre- or absence" is that split constructions in English tend to use prefixes that are [productive or living](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/spelling/prefixes-and-suffixes), which means that they can be applied to other words and readily understood. "[Pre-](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pre-)" (meaning "before") is a living prefix: I could mention having "pre-cold symptoms" and have a good chance at being understood, even if "pre-cold" isn't in the dictionary. "Ab-" is not living, and the "pre-" in "presence" is so integrated with its root in etymology that it goes back to Latin *praesens*, so the wordplay with "pre- or absence" isn't obvious.

Furthermore, the prefix play doesn't work if the root is not itself a word or at least distinguishable when standing alone. *Sence* isn't a recognizable word in English, but the wordplay relies on people recognizing both the prefix and the root independently. That's also why something like "pro- and conductive" wouldn't work well, but why *over- and underachiever* does, as [this bibliography entry shows](https://books.google.com/books?id=b16FG4ClXG8C&pg=PA167&lpg=PA167&dq=Bhatt,%20K.%20K.%20(1971).%20Adjustment%20problems%20of%20Over-%20and%20Underachiever,%20in%20*Second%20Survey%20of%20Research%20in%20Education*,%20M.B.%20Buch%20(ed.),%20Baroda:%20Society%20for%20Educational%20Research%20and%20Development,%201979.&source=bl&ots=o3lriFnkcT&sig=ACfU3U1ryjbpjiqP8FDtrqg9X08oKUTYkQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjawLuU8N_gAhVCWK0KHRruA50Q6AEwAHoECAAQAQ#v=onepage&q=Bhatt%2C%20K.%20K.%20(1971).%20Adjustment%20problems%20of%20Over-%20and%20Underachiever%2C%20in%20*Second%20Survey%20of%20Research%20in%20Education*%2C%20M.B.%20Buch%20(ed.)%2C%20Baroda%3A%20Society%20for%20Educational%20Research%20and%20Development%2C%201979.&f=false):

> Bhatt, K. K. (1971). Adjustment problems of Over- and Underachiever, in *Second Survey of Research in Education*, M.B. Buch (ed.), Baroda: Society for Educational Research and Development, 1979.

That said, your example does occasionally appear in highly technical contexts, perhaps as a vestige of the authors' L1 background as German speakers, or because the writing is already so verbose that a bit of "pre- and absence" can pass by. Here's an entry from German authors of a neurophysiology article, "Modeling crossmodal interactions in emotional audiovisual integration":

> The models differed in a) **[the pre- and absence](https://www.thieme-connect.com/products/ejournals/abstract/10.1055/s-0032-1301610)** of reciprocal interhemispheric connections between FFG, STG and pSTS  ...

Otherwise, this wordplay will tend to appear where both prefixes are living and readily modular, and where the audience would be familiar enough with the root to get the gist. For example,

> **[Pre and Post-Workout](https://yurielkaim.com/pre-and-post-workout-nutrition/)** Nutrition: The Untold Truth
>
> What postmodern knowledge offers classical music is the chance to acknowledge and explore, **[to de- and reconstruct](https://books.google.com/books?id=MfVZQTfYSbMC&pg=PA33&lpg=PA33&dq=%22de-%20and%20reconstruct%22&source=bl&ots=khaieTRkJe&sig=ACfU3U3BsDiLKlph3pChRTlXsF4P-4BmXA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjuur-Lt9_gAhWod98KHfs2CYYQ6AEwCXoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22de-%20and%20reconstruct%22&f=false)**, its relationship to modern subjectivity ...

The former seems natural to me; the latter seems fine to me insofar as *deconstruct* is a technical term and *reconstruct* is a logical counterpart. In contrast, *de- and construct* feels weird, because *struct* would not be as likely understood as a word.

**Edited to add**: For more rigorous exploration, I just found an article on the subject, which argues that there are additional phonological characteristics to be considered, including vocal stresses. In effect, Okada claims that these combinations are only possible when both the coordinated prefix and the morpheme absent the prefixes can be assigned a stress and *are* assigned a stress. This phonological quality - the capacity to be stressed - is held in lexical words like nouns, verbs, and adjectives. Thus the **affix and the remnant have to be capable of functioning like a standalone word in its ability to be stressed**. From there, other specific considerations may also come into play.

Sadayuki Okada, (1999). [On the conjoinability of affixal morphemes in English](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/00437956.1999.11432492), *Word*, 50:3, 339-363, DOI: 10.1080/00437956.1999.11432492 .

> Affixal morpheme conjoinings are possible **only when both the
> conjuncts and the remnants are stress-assignable (i.e., constituting
> heavy syllables), and are actually assigned a stress**, irrespective
> of whether it is an intrinsic stress or a contrastive
> stress.

...

> What really counts is the proper and strict correspondence between the semantic unit of a morpheme and its phonological realization. The matching of the two aspects, with the assignment of a stress, enables a morpheme to stand alone and function as a conjunct. It is important to note again that all lexical words satisfy the conditions to be met by the affixal morphemes functioning as conjuncts or remnants. In other words, **it  is  only when affixal morphemes satisfy the basic requirements for a word-level unit that they can be the target of the conjoining operation**.

Comment: Thanks!  Could you please add references to the quotations?

Comment: **de- and reconstruction** might pass, but  **de- and construction** is quite unnatural.

Comment: @Toothrot Clarify on references. I've included links to the quotations.

Comment: @TRomano I thought of another aspect that would explain that. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the links.

Comment: +1 for the article, which has many examples.

Comment: Not sure what Okada means by "semantic *unit*".

Comment: @TRomano I understand "semantic unit" to specify what kind of unit a "morpheme" is: it's a semantic one, or one pertaining to the meaning of the string of letters. Similarly, Okada considers a syllable to be a *phonological unit*: "It will be
proven in the course of the survey that the strict correspondence between
the semantic unit of morphemes and the phonological unit of syllables
has to be maintained in all the cases where the conjoining of morphemes
is judged to be well-formed.